# Why the while loop is executed more than once?

Tags: c

I have got a question in the interview for which I had to find out the output of the following code. I tried but it was not correct. Please explain the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=0,a;
    while(x++ < 5)
    {
        a=x;
        printf("a = %d \n",a);
        static int x=3;
        printf("x = %d \n",x);
        x+=2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 1
x = 3
a = 2
x = 5
a = 3
x = 7
a = 4
x = 9
a = 5
x = 11
```

Can anyone please explain whats going on here?

Comment: If you rename the static inner variable `x` in the last three lines of your loop body, you should see what happens more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

The loop conditional expression `x++ < 5` uses the `x` declared outside the loop. The statement `x += 2;` is not affecting the `x` declared outside the loop because `static int x=3;` hides the previous declaration of `x`.

In other words, all modifications to `x` after the statement `static int x=3;` is not affecting the `x` used in loop controlling expression.

Comment: I removed the static even then the loop is executed 5 times see. [link](http://ideone.com/x1U3Ph)

Comment: @SatishPatel ,`static` or not,`x` in the loop shadows the outer `x`

Comment: @SatishPatel; It has nothing to do with `static`. Redeclaration of `x` in loop will hide its all previous declarations.

Comment: When the both x are in the same code segment then how the `static int x` is being differed from `outer int x` by the compiler?

Comment: @haccks when the `static int x` re-declaration hides the previous declaration then its updated value should be reflected in the while loop condition

Comment: In C the scope of a symbol starts at it's "declarator" (right after the  "=" character). It ends with the end of the compound statement (the "}" character). So the second `x` is visible only in the last three lines of the loop body. All other `x` refer to the first variable.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `x++` returns the current value of `x` and then is incremented.

In the first iteration,

```
while(x++ < 5)
```

is same as

```
while(0 < 5)
```

Then,after the condition has been checked,`x` will be incremented. Thus the value of `a` is the incremented value of `x`. The `static x`,shadows(hides) the `x` declared outside the loop and hence,

```
x+=2;
```

affects the `static x` and not the outer one. The variable `x` declared in the loop,since it is `static` exists as long as the program does and will not be lost once it goes out of scope. It will be initialized to 3 and 2 will be added in each iteration of the loop to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to:

```
int x=0,a;
int y=3;
while(x++ < 5)
{
    a=x;
    printf("a = %d \n",a);
    printf("x = %d \n",y);
    y+=2;
}
```

The second `x` was hiding the first `x`.

Comment: "This is equivalent to..."—except when running the function twice (where the static object will not be initialized a second time). Not likely with `main`, though.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe yes, but we could just qualify `y` as `static` here but as it didn't add anything in this specific case I preferred to remove it.